# Compare time only in sql database (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, sql

i wanna compare time and show records that are greater than the spcified time. For example in my database I have a field "TimeDate" where I store date and time together. Now i want to show records that are only greater than lets say this time "19/04/2012 2:34:27 PM". Is there anyway I can achieve this.

I have started with this code.

```
Select * from Table where TimeDate > '19/04/2012 2:34:27 PM'.
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score -2):

First of all the datatype is datetime in sql,

your sample code is right.

I am sure that sql is intelligent enough, for your current query.